# Excel patterns or increments

Tags: excel, formula, increment, drag

I was wondering if there is a way to make a formula than uses a cell n times, for example:

```
=concatenate(A1,", ","some string")
=concatenate(A1,", ","some string")
=concatenate(A2,", ","some string")
=concatenate(A2,", ","some string")
```

and so on.
Here what I want to show is that cell A1 is repeated 2 times, then A2 two times as well, etc.
How can I achieve that with just drag the cells down.

And also I need to achieve this:

`A      B    C
one    dog  one dog
two    cat  one cat
three       two dog
four        two cat
            three dog
            three cat`

in this case, I want to concatenate the values from column B, thats why I need to repeat it two times

Answer (score 3):

You can use an Index function to identify which cell to concatenate. For a regular pattern of using every row twice, use

```
=CONCATENATE(INDEX(A:A,ROUNDUP(ROW()/2,0)),", ","some string")
```

Copy down.

[image]

Comment: Nice! Better than using `INDIRECT` which is volatile and should thus be avoided where possible.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&(MOD(ROW(),2)+ROW())/2)&", some string"
```

A version for repetition three times:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&FLOOR(1+(ROW()-1)/3,1))&", some string"
```

or for repetition two times with alternating strings from B1:B2 :

```
=INDIRECT("A"&(MOD(ROW(),2)+ROW())/2)&" "&IF(ISODD(ROW()),B$1,B$2)
```

Once the formulae have achieved the appropriate expansion they should be selected, Copy, Paste Special, Values over the top to replace the formulae with the results of the formulae.

Comment: Hi, I tried it and I get that the cell is repeated 6 times instead of 3, do you know why?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say that I tried to do it for 3 replacing the 2 for a 3 =INDIRECT("A"&(MOD(ROW(),3)+ROW())/23)&", some string" and it is repeated 6 times

Comment: Hey sorry looks like I made a mistake, everything its correct, thanks

Answer (score -1):

Not that I know of without using VBA, but you could change the formula (assuming those formulas start in cell `b1`) to:

```
=concatenate(indirect(A1),", ","some string")
```

and then in cell `A1` you'd type in whatever cell you wanted to reference, so in cell `A1` you'd type in `a1` and then in cell `A2` you'd type in `a1` again.

Comment: "*in cell A1 you'd type in a1 and then in cell A2 you'd type in a1 again.*" The words "defeating the purpose" come to mind.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett agreed, and the other answer is better